# Searching for 32-bit ELF file

Tags: fedora, 32bit, elf

I wonder if there is any possibility to find files which are 32-bit ELF objects by using one single command in file system? I'm actually working in fedora 23 64 bit and can't locate any of those files but the exercise which I'm trying to do precisely says that it must be 32-bit ELF file. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is check that the first 5 bytes in the file are 7f 45 4c 46 01 (that's what `file` does). So you only need to read 5 bytes off every file:

```
PERLIO=:raw find . -type f -size +51c -exec perl -lne '
  BEGIN{$/=\5};print $ARGV if $_ eq "\x7f\x45\x4c\x46\x01"; close ARGV' {} +
```

Here checking only regular files that are at least 52 bytes as that's the size of [the ELF header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header) for a 32 bit ELF file, though ELF files would generally be a lot bigger than that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -exec file '{}' \; | grep -i 'elf 32'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like the `file` command used like this?

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=cecbb9e27978d91bc6fe2cc4d46d0cd58deafdb2, stripped
$
```

You could do a `find` command piped to `file` as follows:

```
$ find /bin -type f -exec file '{}' \; | grep -c "ELF 32-bit LSB  executable" 
88
$ find /bin -type f -exec file '{}' \; 2>&1  | grep  "ELF 32-bit LSB  executable" | head -2
/bin/bzip2: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=8ec5364bf1b5aae5a29b02aaa89db511e988f26a, stripped
/bin/more: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=2cf8c3651ba3e5dd6a053d40a969b4b7bca9cac0, stripped
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file` command and look for the keyword `executable` in the output of this command. If found, grab the first 2 fields with `awk`, i.e., `$1` and `$2`. there lies your answer. You can build a logic to do whatever you want to do with the 32-bit ELF files. Also you can look through the files in directories of your desire, in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to get the files, then `file` to get the file info and `grep` to search for the string `32-bit` in the `file`'s output:

```
find /bin /usr/bin -type f -exec sh -c '{ file -L "$1" | grep -q 32-bit ;} \
      && echo "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Change/add location(s) to search to fit your need.

**Example:**

```
% find /usr/bin -type f -exec sh -c '{ file -L "$1" | grep -q 32-bit ;} && echo "$1"' _ {} \; 
/usr/bin/unix2dos
/usr/bin/dos2unix
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways to do it. Instead of printing all file names
I added `| wc -l` at the end of every suggested command to prove that
they return the same:

1. use `find` in conjunction with `-exec`:

   ```
   $ time find . -type f  -exec file {} \;  | grep -i "ELF 32" | wc -l
   2872

   real    0m7.422s
   user    0m5.095s
   sys     0m0.384s
   ```
2. use `find` in conjunction with `xargs` - note that although it's
   much faster it's less safe as `xargs` will run a given command even if
   `find` returns no results and `-r` option used here is a GNU extension
   and is not specified `POSIX`:

   ```
   $ time find . -type f  | xargs -r file | grep "ELF 32" | wc -l
   2872

   real    0m1.754s
   user    0m1.712s
   sys     0m0.052s
   ```
3. use `grep` to manually check header of each file. `-r` here is to
   ignore symlinks:

   ```
   $ grep -l -a -m1 $'^\x7F\x45\x4c\x46\x01' -r . | wc -l
   2872
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Single-command recursive search for 32-bit ELF files:

```
$ scanelf -M32 -R /SEARCH/PATH
 TYPE   FILE 
ET_DYN /SEARCH/PATH/library.so
ET_EXEC /SEARCH/PATH/executable
```

Also, suppressing banner and object type (printing only filepaths):

```
$ scanelf -M32 -RBF %F /SEARCH/PATH
/SEARCH/PATH/library.so
/SEARCH/PATH/executable
```